# How do I hardcode asset id's?

Tags: pallet, assets, pallet-treasury

Using pallet-assets, how do I create a pallet that has hardcoded (pallet-)asset id's for it's on-chain assets that the pallet handles?

I wasnt able to find a good documented way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Because AssetId's are mostly a fancy way of saying u32, It's as simple as:

```
let first_asset_id: T::AssetId = 1u32.into();
```

Don't forget to Add `From<u32>` in :

```rust
type AssetId: IsType<<Self as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId>
            + Parameter
            + From<u32>
            + Ord
            + Copy;
```

The implementation can be found here:
https://github.com/liberland/liberland_substrate/blob/65edb6bab3/frame/llm/src/lib.rs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, the answer above does not work for me.
if I try:

```
let nbr:u32 = 10;
let val:AssetId = nbr.into();
```

I get:

```
the trait From<u32> is not implemented for <T as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId
```

Any advice on how to solve it?
Kazu.

Comment: you can see the implementation here: https://github.com/liberland/liberland_substrate/blob/main/frame/llm/src/lib.rs#L140, I put T::Assetid as ``` type AssetId: IsType<<Self as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId>
   + Parameter
   + From<u32>
   + Ord
   + Copy;```