# Updating AssetId when using pallet_assets

Tags: pallet, assets, types

I am trying to use the pallet_asset, but the AssetId type is giving me some trouble.

**Try nbr.1:**

- Create a storage value TokenId that takes a u32
- Create the AssetId from the u32 inside the storage:

  `let token_id: T::AssetId = TokenId::<T>::get().unwrap().into();`
- I get the following error:

  `the trait 'From<u32>' is not implemented for '<T as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId'`

**Try nbr.2:**

- Use the type AssetId instead of u32 inside the storage
- After using `pallet_assets::Pallet::<T>::force_create(...,AssetId,...);`, update the AssetId
  inside the storage as demonstrated
  here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/assets

  `TokenId::<T>::mutate(|val|{*val +=1});`
- This time I get:

  `cannot use '+=' on type 'core::option::Option<<T as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId>'`

Any idea on how I can solve this problem? what am I missing?
Kazu

Comment: I did an implementation and answered this here:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/how-do-i-hardcode-asset-ids

Comment: Wow thank you!! this was a tricky one!!